# Showing $\mathbb{R}^3$ minus $n$ parallel lines is homotopic to $\mathbb{R}^2\setminus\{p_1,\dots,p_n\}$

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory

I want to show that if I remove $n$ parallel lines from $\mathbb{R}^3$ then I get $\mathbb{R}^2\setminus \{p_1,\dots,p_n\}.$

There is also some underlying structure I wish to also understand. That is, $\pi_1(x_0,\mathbb{R}^2\setminus\{p\})$ is $\mathbb{Z}$. Does this generalize? More precisely, is $\pi_1(x_0,\mathbb{R}^2\setminus\{p_1,\dots,p_n\}) =\mathbb{Z}^n$?

Comment: If the lines are parallel, there shouldn't be any harm in assuming they're orthogonal to the $xy$-plane in $\mathbb{R}^3$. After removing them, you can project everything onto the plane, which now has $n$ punctures from where the lines went through it. This punctured plane is homotopy equivalent to a wedge sum of spheres, since you can pick some point, and then draw loops out from it encircling all the punctures and then retract. To generalize, the fundamental group of the wedge of circles is a free product of copies of $\mathbb{Z}$, not the direct product, by van Kampen.

Comment: Hmm I see. What about if they are not orthogonal, and are just non intersecting. IE $y=1, y=2$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Call the lines $L_1, \dots, L_n$.

Let $w$ be a direction vector for the lines, and let $P$ be the plane through the origin with normal vector $w$. Note, all the lines are orthogonal to $P$.

Let $\{u, v\}$ be a basis for $P$, then $\{u, v, w\}$ is a basis for $\mathbb{R}^3$. Define the linear transformation $T : \mathbb{R}^3 \to \mathbb{R}^3$ by $T(u) = e_1$, $T(v) = e_2$, and $T(w) = e_3$. Note that $T$ sends $P$ to the $xy$-plane, and the lines orthogonal to $P$ to lines orthogonal to the $xy$-plane (i.e. lines with direction vector $e_3$); let $\ell_i = T(L_i)$. As $T$ is invertible, it is a homeomorphism so $\mathbb{R}^3\setminus\{L_1, \dots, L_n\}$ is homotopy equivalent to $\mathbb{R}^3\setminus\{\ell_1, \dots, \ell_n\}$.

If $\pi$ denotes the projection $\mathbb{R}^3 \to \mathbb{R}^2$ given by $\pi(x, y, z) = (x, y)$, let $p_i$ be the projection under $\pi$ of the point at which $\ell_i$ intersects the $xy$-plane. Then $\pi$ restricts to a map $\pi : \mathbb{R}^3\setminus\{\ell_1, \dots, \ell_n\} \to \mathbb{R}^2\setminus\{p_1, \dots, p_n\}$. We also have the inclusion $i : \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}^3$ given by $i(x, y) = (x, y, 0)$. Note that $i$ restricts to a map $i : \mathbb{R}^2\setminus\{p_1, \dots, p_n\} \to \mathbb{R}^3\setminus\{\ell_1, \dots, \ell_n\}$.

While $\pi\circ i : \mathbb{R}^2\setminus\{p_1, \dots, p_n\} \to \mathbb{R}^2\setminus\{p_1, \dots, p_n\}$ is the identity map, $i\circ\pi : \mathbb{R}^3\setminus\{\ell_1, \dots, \ell_n\} \to \mathbb{R}^3\setminus\{\ell_1, \dots, \ell_n\}$ is given by $(i\circ\pi)(x, y, z) = (x, y, 0)$. Note however that $i\circ\pi$ is homotopic to the identity map via the homotopy

\begin{align*}
H : (\mathbb{R}^3\setminus\{\ell_1, \dots, \ell_n\})\times[0, 1] &\to \mathbb{R}^3\setminus\{\ell_1, \dots, \ell_n\}\\
H((x, y, z), t) &= (x, y, tz).
\end{align*}

Therefore, $\pi$ and $i$ are homotopy inverses, so $\mathbb{R}^3\setminus\{\ell_1, \dots, \ell_n\}$ and $\mathbb{R}^2\setminus\{p_1, \dots, p_n\}$ are homotopy equivalent. As homotopy equivalence is transitive, $\mathbb{R}^3\setminus\{L_1, \dots, L_n\}$ and $\mathbb{R}^2\setminus\{p_1, \dots, p_n\}$ are homotopy equivalent.

As for your question about fundamental groups, note that $\mathbb{R}^2\setminus\{p_1, \dots, p_n\}$ is homotopy equivalent to a bouquet of $n$ circles, the fundamental group of which is $F_n$, the free group on $n$ generators. Note, this is not the same group as $\mathbb{Z}^n$ unless $n = 1$. For example, if $n > 1$, $F_n$ is not abelian while $\mathbb{Z}^n$ is.

Comment: This is one of those situations where visualising what's happening is much easier than writing it down explicitly.

Comment: This is 100% crystal clear. Thank you!

Comment: Also I think you mean $\mathbb{R}^2$  for $H:...$

Comment: Actually I meant $\mathbb{R}^3\setminus\{\ell_1, \dots, \ell_n\}$. I have edited accordingly.